# Android Development Missing "drawable" folder (NetBeans IDE)

Tags: android, netbeans, directory, drawable

I recently switched to Ubuntu and decided to use NetBeans for Java development instead of Eclipse which I used on Windows.

The problem is, in the Eclipse I used on Windows, I had a folder named "drawable-hdpi" with the standard app icon in and a few other folders like "drawable-mdpi" (I think).

But with NetBeans, there doesn't seem to be any folders named "drawable".

Is this right, or is there something wrong that I need to fix?

Thanks for reading,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should use eclipse. Does netbeans even have an android plugin?

2.) just create the folder

Comment: Yeah, it does. I followed this guide (http://gerry.ws/2009/01/1074/how-to-setup-netbeans-for-android-development.html) to set mine up.

Guess I'll just have to do that for now then.

Comment: I would really suggest just using eclipse. Any reason you want to use netbeans?